# Respond to only the first WM_KEYDOWN notification?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, notifications

How can a Win32 application respond to only the first WM_KEYDOWN notification?  The MSDN docs claim bit 30 "Specifies the previous key state. The value is 1 if the key is down before the message is sent, or it is zero if the key is up." but bit 30 is always 0 in my WndProc.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    // ToDo - stop multiple notifications for repeating keys
    printf("WM_KEYDOWN %i %i", wParam, lParam & 30);
    return 0;
```

Is **lParam & 30** the wrong way to ask for this?  Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: How did you end up implementing this? repeatCount=(lParam & 0xffff); if(repeatCount < 1) Action(); Doesn't seem to work for me. Nor does repeatCount < 2. I either get repeating keys or no key press at all.

Comment: I used:  if ((lParam & (1 << 30)) == 0)... although if (lParam & 0x40000000) worked as well if I remember correctly.  My choice was based on readability (1 << 30) makes more sense to me than 0x40000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get bit 30, you need this:

```
(lParam & 0x40000000)
```

An alternative would be to use bits 0-15 to get the repeat count:

```
int repeatCount = (lParam & 0xffff)
```

and only do anything if the repeat count is 0 (or possibly 1; I'm not sure whether the first message gets a repeat count of 0 or 1, and it's not clear from the documentation).

Comment: This worked - thank you.  My bit fiddling-fu is a little shaky.  What exactly is 0x40000000?

Comment: That's a DWORD representing a bitmask consisting of bit 30 set and all other bits cleared.

Comment: You might want to read an introduction to hexadecimal, eg. http://www.learn-programming.za.net/articles_decbinhexoct.html It's not too hard, but not so trivial that I can explain it all here.

Answer (score 12):

To test bit 30 don't AND with 30, instead AND with 1 << 30.

```
const bool isBitSet = lParam & (1 << 30);
```

Comment: It probably does read better but it has to be computed every time (unless the compiler is optimizing this). 0x4000000 Will be faster.

Comment: VC++7 is optimizing it to a constant value.

Comment: @kjfletch those kind of micro optimizations are certainly not needed anymore.. Any simple compiler could optimize that..

Comment: @kjfletch How much faster was it even if not optimized when you timed it?  WM_KEYDOWN events come in only once every 1 million nanoseconds in my test, and it takes what, like 1 ns to shift a bit?  Unless the bit is really, really, *REALLY* heavy; then it takes _maybe_ 3.5 ns.  _Max._

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise AND `(lParam & 0x4000000)` will work but you can easily make it more readable using the defines included with Windows.h (which you're already using for `WM_KEYDOWN`):

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if((HIWORD(lParam) & KF_REPEAT) == 0) //process wParam
    return 0;
```

`HIWORD` takes the most significant 16 bits.

`KF_REPEAT` (= 0x4000) flags the location of the bit representing a repeat `WM_KEYDOWN` message.

The bitwise AND of these values equals 0 when the repeat flag is off (the initial keypress) and equals 1 every subsequent time (the autorepeat feature) until the key is released.

It's a small thing but it goes a long way to improving the readability of your code. `0x40000000` does not mean anything to the reader while much can be inferred from  `KF_REPEAT`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing lParam & 30 is that, '30' over here is considered to be in decimal, which when converted to binary would '11110'. Hence you are not testing bit 30 but just getting the result for lparam & 11110.

Hope this helps in clarifying the problem a bit.