# Is It Worth Using Bitwise Operators In Methods?

Tags: java, optimization, bitwise-operators

I am very new to Java (and programming in general, my previous experience is with ActionScript 2.0 and some simple JavaScript), and I am working my way slowly and methodically through Java: A Beginner's Guide by Herbert Schildt. It is an incredible book.

For one thing, I finally understand more-or-less what bitwise operators (which I first encountered in ActionScript 2.0) do, and that they are more efficient than other methods for certain sums.

My question is, is it more efficient to use a method that uses, say, a shift right, to perform all your divisions/2 (or divisions/even) for you in a large program with many calculations (in this case, a sprawling RPG), or is it more efficient to simply use standard mathematical operations because the compiler will optimise it all for you?

Or, am I asking the wrong question entirely?

Comment: There are two rules for optimizations. 1. Don't  2. *(experts only)* Don't yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is shifting bits faster than multiplying and dividing in Java? .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net)

Comment: Haha, thank you. I will probably end up trying and enjoying a glorious failure or 3 anyway long before I am ready.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question entirely. The question you should be asking is "should I keep my code simple and readable, or use tricks that I believe will improve its performance, even though I haven't measured its performance." The answer should be obvious.

Bitwise operators have their place, especially when you're dealing with binary file formats that need to pack a lot of data into small space. And it's absolutely critical to know how to mask out the high bits of a byte so that you don't accidentally sign-extend (print out these two variables to see what I mean):

```
byte b = (byte)0xDC;
int  i = b & 0xFF;
```

But don't go looking for places to use these operators, especially to replace such simple tasks as dividing by 2.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's exactly what I was looking for, and it explains it in a simple and easy to understand way.  I am easily impressed by clever tricks, and it's sometimes a leap for me to understand that clever tricks are usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

Optimizations like this should only be done if you have a real NEED to do it.  If you simply think the code will run faster, it may not be worth it.

Often times the compiler may be smarter than you think, and do the optimizations for you, other times there may be caveats that only get you deeper in trouble.  In top of that (and probably the biggest reason against doing this), is that if it makes your code hard to read/understand for future developers (or yourself), you may only be adding more anti-optimizations in the future trying to work around the original code.

Comment: Cheers! I'd hate to make my code hard to read or understand for other developers. I like your point about the caveats that get you deeper in trouble, there is so much to learn not just about languages but about computers that I can easily imagine there being hundreds of technical problems per 'improvement'.

Comment: Your code will always be read by two people: yourself, and then yourself 6 months from now.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the compiler does a lot of optimizations. Also you need to investigate what your bottleneck really is before you go optimizing it. Optimizing things that are not the bottleneck just leads to more of your threads hitting the real bottleneck faster. Look up constraint theory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am looking up constraint theory as I type this.

Comment: @user1626141: yes, googling that now and it looks not as directly relevant as I'd thought. Really the important thing is that you measure first before optimizing, so that you know you're improving something that's on the critical path. Optimizing everything just because you can is almost always either a waste of time or actually a source of possible performance problems. And then of course there's the nastiness you introduce into the codebase. Bit-twiddling is fun and there's a place for it, just make sure you take some measurements to make sure it's justified.

Answer (score 3):

For learning purpose you can skip optimizing your code that way. It requires some experience otherwise you may face problems debugging your code (I mainly mean "what the heck is this thing doing?" syndrome) Compilers nowadays are smart enough to optimize the output code and deal with known patterns the right way. Unless you are going to really need to save each millisecond or cpu cycle, focus on keeping your code clean.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I doubt I'll need to save every millisecond! Clean code it is. This is what I like about coding in any case, the clarity.

Comment: I like your approach. You will end well in this business :)

Answer (score 2):

The latter. Which is to say, write your code in the most clear way possible first, which will most likely entail standard mathematical operations. Let the compiler take care of the rest.

Java, because it runs on a VM, has other interesting built-in optimization features: for example, as your program runs, the VM can see which branches of code are being executed most frequently and make those branches more efficient.

Once you write your program, then use a profiling tool to measure which specific methods are slow. Once you know that, then you will know what kind of code to optimize. For example, you might find that reading a configuration from a file is the slowest thing you do, and you can look for ways to make that faster. My hunch is that you're not likely to find any performance benefit at all by using things like bitwise operators rather than normal arithmetic.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for wishing me luck, I appreciate it :) I will look into using a profiling tool only once my program is functional.

Answer (score 0):

> For one thing, I finally understand more-or-less what bitwise
>   operators (which I first encountered in ActionScript 2.0) do, and that
>   they are more efficient than other methods for certain sums.

No this is wrong here. Bitwise operations has more applications that doing a division or multiplication that you ask about.
You can efficiently use bitmasks as flags, to pack values, to emulate access rights in compact manner, in crytography etc etc.
See this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559657/are-bitwise-operations-still-practical/6559712#6559712)
You should search for more applications than just read a chapter that says about how a shift is similar and (perhaps) faster than a division (not necessarily as the compiler would convert to shift anyway)

Comment: Hi, yes, I read about some of the other applications of bitwise operators while searching for other uses. They are a bit beyond me at present, no pun intended. The division was just intended as an example.