# about & and | operation

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real world use cases of bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096916/real-world-use-cases-of-bitwise-operators)

I'm not quite sure about bitwise operator `&` and `|`, can someone explain to me what exactly these operator do?
I have read tutorial in http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html yesterday, butIi don't really know if I want to apply it in coding, can someone please give some examples .

Comment: Have you considered picking up [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? Such a book will explain this and much more.

Comment: what exactly is it that you do not understand? The tutorial you provided is pretty extensive

Answer (score 0):

the `|` operator (OR):

```
------------------------
 a  0000 1110 1110 0101
------------------------
 b  1001 0011 0100 1001
------------------------
a|b 1001 1111 1110 1101
```

the operator gives `1` if there is `1` in the spot in one of the numbers.

the `&` operator (AND):

```
------------------------
 a  0000 1110 1110 0101
------------------------
 b  1001 0011 0100 1001
------------------------
a&b 0000 0010 0100 0001
```

the operator gives `0` if in one of the numbers.

**usage:** if I want just part of the number (lets say the second set of four) i could write:

`a & 0x00f0`

the usage of bit operators is **not** recommended for starters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very low-level programming question. The smallest bit of memory is the "bit". A byte is a chunk of 8 bits, a word a chunk of 16 bits and so on... Bitwise operators let you alter/check the bits of these chunks. Depending upon what you're writing code for you may never need these operators.

Examples:

```
unsigned char x = 10; /*This declares a byte and sets it to 10. The binary representation
                        of this value is 00001010. The ones and zeros are the bits.*/

if (x & 2) {
  //Number 2 is binary 00000010, so the statements within this condition will be executed 
  //if the bit #1 is set (bits are numbered from right to left starting from #0) 
}

unsigned char y = x | 1; //This makes `y` equal to x and sets the bit #0. 
                         //I.e. y = 00001010 | 00000001 = 00001011 = 11 decimal
```