# What is << stand for in ruby with integer

Tags: ruby, integer, operators

What is use of  `<<` I understand in array it is used for push but here I am not clear what is purpose of this in following code. Where it is being used integer.

```
def array_pack(a)
    a.reverse.reduce(0) { |x, b| (x << 8) + b }
end

array_pack([24, 85, 0]) # will print 21784
```

like if I x is 8 and I write `8 << 8` it gives me response of `2048` so is it converting in bytes? or what exact is its purpose.

Comment: The documentation is your friend: [`Integer#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Integer.html#3C-3C-method) :-)

Comment: it is saying changing location but still not clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, [Integer:<<](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Integer.html#3C-3C-method) - Returns the integer shifted left "X" positions, or right if "X" is negative. In your scenario is shifts 8 positions to the left.

Here is how it works:

```
8.to(2) => "1000"
```

Now let's shift `"1000"` 8 positions to the left

```
(8 << 8).to_s(2) => "100000000000"
```

If you count the `0` above you will see it added `8` after `"1000"`.

Now, let's see how it returns `2048`

```
"100000000000".to_i(2) => 2048
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a Bitwise LEFT shift operator.

Definition:

```
The LEFT SHIFT operator << shifts each bit of a number to the left by n positions.
```

Example:

If you do `7 << 2 = 28`

7 in Base 2: `0000 0111`

```
    128 64 32 16  8 4 2 1
    ---------------------- 
7:   0  0  0  0   0 1 1 1
```

Now shift each bit to the left by 2 positions

```
    128 64 32 16  8 4 2 1
    ---------------------- 
28:  0  0  0  1   1 1 0 0
```

**Why?**

Bitwise operators are widely used for low-level programming on embedded systems to apply a mask (in this case to integer)

**Benefits**

See this SO answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097062/7009747)

View Source for more details: [link](https://medium.com/rubycademy/ruby-bitwise-operators-da57763fa368)